# Import Native ios/Android Code to Xamarin project

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms

I need to import the native ios and android code in existing **xamarin** project same as *react-native* do for

ios : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios
android:https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android

is it possible to achieve in **xamarin**?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I do not know how does the `native modules` work in `React Native`, however, there are `Native Bindings` that you could create and use in your `Xamarin` project.

[Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/native-libraries):

> Xamarin.Android supports the use of native libraries via the standard
>   PInvoke mechanism. You can also bundle additional native libraries
>   which are not part of the OS into your .apk.

[iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/):

> Xamarin.iOS supports linking with both native C libraries and
>   Objective-C libraries.

Comment: Hii@EvZ, i have experience with native modules OF ReactNative, if talk about ios, than we just create a project in objective-c/swift and using ReactBridge File, we import to React-native project.

Comment: So,for example if i create a media player in ios/android native ..than could i import my native using above steps..or i need to create framework of that code?

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. I am pretty sure you will find the answers if you will read the documentation links (Android & iOS) carefully.